# Odoo python fileopendialog

Tags: python, odoo, fileopendialog

does anybody knows how to open a filedialog on Odoo? I've add a button on a custom view, now I would like to browse for a file on THE CLIENT when this button is clicked.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define binary fields in Odoo, like other fields. Look into ir.attachment model definition and its view definitions to get a good hint, how do it for such fields.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a custom widget for this. object buttons trigger actions in server side not client side

You can find more about widgets in the ofoocial documentation [odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html) also you may find some examples of odoo widgets in addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js If you want just to upload a file you don't have to go through all of this you may use the binary field of odoo and the task is handled by odoo.